# Let expression for multiple variables in XPath 3.0

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-3.0

I want to declare 2-3 variables using a function `let` and run a separate loop `for` for each variable. How can i do this?

I can use only XPath 3.0.

Thanks in advance.

I tried expressions like this, but they don't work:
1)
`let $x := a, $y := b return (for $var1 in $x return expr1), (for $var2 in $y return expr2)`

2. `return (for $var1 in $x return expr1, for $var2 in $y return expr2)`
3. `return for $var1 in $x return expr1, for $var2 in $y return expr2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in XPath 3.0 is

```
[11]    LetExpr    ::=      
          SimpleLetClause "return" ExprSingle
[12]    SimpleLetClause    ::=      
          "let" SimpleLetBinding ("," SimpleLetBinding)*
[13]    SimpleLetBinding   ::=      
          "$" VarName ":=" ExprSingle
```

I believe that the construct:

```
let $x := a, $y := b 
return (for $var1 in $x return expr1, for $var2 in $y return expr2)
```

should work, though I don't have an XPath 3.0 processor to try it on. It's certainly working in XPath 3.1.